# Get latest available version for user appstore and play market

Tags: react-native, google-play, app-store

I have some problem, I need to check latest available app version for current user with react-native. I made phased release for 20% users for appstore and google play market, but package react-native-version-check send me latest app version for all users (some user should get available version, not latest). How can I get latest available version for user?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **react-native-device-info** to get the current app version of your users then you can use **react-native-check-version** to compare it with the AppStore or play store version.

```
import { checkVersion, CheckVersionResponse } from "react-native-check-version";
import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info';

// version update check
const [version, setVersion]: [CheckVersionResponse | undefined, Dispatch<SetStateAction<CheckVersionResponse | undefined>>] = useState<CheckVersionResponse | undefined>(undefined)     
const currentVersion: string = DeviceInfo.getVersion()

async function checkV(): Promise<void> {
        const version = await checkVersion({
            currentVersion: currentVersion
        })

   setVersion(version)
}

useEffect(() => {
   checkV()
}, [])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how I can check is latest version is available for current user (I use phased release, so not all users can get this version)

Comment: I think this method will give the update option for your user if available update because the user will see the new version in the AppStore and on the user device this method gets the latest available version.

Answer (score 0):

```
import VersionCheck from 'react-native-version-check';
import {Linking } from 'react-native';

versioncontrol = async () =>{
    VersionCheck.needUpdate()
    .then(async res => {
      if (res.isNeeded) {
       Linking.openURL(res.storeUrl)
    
      }else{
        console.log("Update Not Available")
    }).catch(error => {
     console.log(error)
    })
 
  }
```